# Which kind of Google Cloud Platform mobile backend client is appropriate?

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, mobile, google-cloud-platform, backend

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm writing a mobile app which will allow a user to log in, save some preferences that must be stored in a database, and display congressional bills to the user.

I've only written simple RESTful services with PHP and MySQL in the past. I'd like to take advantage of newer technologies, and am a little lost on general direction.

The bill data (*formatted as JSON*) can be gathered by running the scrapers found [here](https://github.com/unitedstates/congress). Using docker, I managed to set a working directory and download the files on my local machine.

I've designed a MySQL database for holding the relevant bill and user data.

I started to mess around in Google Cloud Platform, and read the [doc that describes different models](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#compute-engine-rest-grpc). I'm thinking of a few different ideas, but aren't familiar with GCP or what I can actually accomplish.

**QUESTIONS**

1) What are App Engine, Compute Engine, and Container Engine each for? I get the gist that Container Engine holds different instances of stuff you load up with docker, and that Compute Engine sets up a VM, but I don't really understand the relationships. How should I think of them?

2) When I run those scrapers from the shell, where are the files being stored, and how can I check on them? On my computer, I set a working directory, but how do directories work in GCP? Is it just a directory in the currently selected VM, or is this what Buckets are for?

**IDEAS**

1) Since my bill data already comes as JSON, should I skip the entire process of building a database for the bills and insert them into Firebase somehow? Is this even possible? If so, am I stuck using Firebase's NoSQL, or can I still set up a relational database?

2) I could schedule the scrapers to run periodically, detect new files, and run a script to parse the JSON and insert new bill data into my a database (PostgrSQL?/MySQL?). Then I would write an API.

3) Download the JSON files to a bucket, and write an API that reads from them. Not sure how the performance would compare to using a DB.

I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Why is Firebase's NoSQL database unsuitable for your goals? If you're only going to store a list of bills without a lot of relationships, you won't get any performance or reliability boost from using an RDBMS.

Comment: There's a lot more to the system. I'll have various kinds of accounts, allow people to create and join organizations, conduct polls, etc. On a personal note I'm unfamiliar with NoSQL and already wrote my schema for MySQL, so I am hesitant to jump over unless there's a good case. Maybe NoSQL is a better choice and I just don't understand all it can do? Please elaborate.

Comment: its too broad for this forum. you first need to do much more research on your alternatives to understand them well, like nosql and appengine/gce concepts.

Comment: Can you recommend a forum where it's not too broad? This is a lot of new technologies to juggle, and my time table does not permit me to research everything possible. A simple "yeah idea X should work" would be a huge help since it would let me focus more.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case (stateless web application), App Engine is probably your best choice. The Google documentation [has](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#choosing_an_option) [several](https://cloud.google.com/docs/choosing-a-compute-option)[comparisons](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/) [of your computing options](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/cloud-platform-services)

You can use [App Engine with PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/quickstart) and [cloud-hosted MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/) if you want, which could be a good way to get your toes wet without going in over your head.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm leaning toward. I'll post back with whatever I end up doing.